# Order of HttpApplication.BeginRequest vs Application_BeginRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, lifecycle

I am trying to understand if it's safe to assume that a BeginRequest-subscription in a class implementing IHttpModule always execute before Application_BeginRequest in global.asax.cs.

Longer version:

In ASP.NET, I can hook into BeginRequest for a HTTP request in several different places: In a `Global.asax.cs`-class deriving from `HttpApplication`, I can implement `Application_BeginRequest` which will be called when a request is started.

```
private void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Another method is to create an implementation of `IHttpModule`, and subscribe to `BeginRequest` using something like below (and add it as a module in web.config):

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(OnBeginRequest);.
}
```

On https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb470252(v=vs.100), I can see that the request is processed by the HttpApplication pipeline and the order of the events. It also says that:

> ASP.NET automatically binds application events to handlers in the Global.asax file using the naming convention Application_event, such as Application_BeginRequest.

But I am unable to find any documentation explaining the order of these two mechanisms compared to eachother. On my computer, `Application_BeginRequest` consistently execute *after* a `BeginRequest`-subscription in an `IHttpHandler`, but I don't know if it's safe to assume this is always the case.

As I understand it, event subscriptions in .NET are not guaranteed to be sorted, but `Application_BeginRequest` is not a typical event handler.

Comment: I think, you can assume that (but no guaranties). I remember I had a 'EndRequest' handler i Global.asax, that cleaned up resources, that worked fine, so it must have run last.

Comment: However, a better idea is to replace the event (in Global.asax) with an event, that runs later. Then it will be guarantied (you can subscribe to all events there, just like IHttpModule).